What is the symbol $\mathfrak{X}$ for smooth manifolds describing?
In Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" the symbol $\mathfrak{X}$ arises after chapter 12, particularly on page 318:
d) If  $X_1,\dots, X_k\in \mathfrak{X}M$, then the function $A(X_1,\dots, X_k):M\to \mathbb{R}$ $$A(X_1,\dots,X_k)(p)=A_p(X_1\bigg|_p,\dots, X_k\bigg|_p)$$ is smooth.
This is part of the proposition 12.19 for smooth criteria for tensor fields.
What I am not sure about is what the symbol $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ is. My intuition is that it is the space of of tensor bundles over $M$, but I can't be sure.
Can someone confirm?
Thanks

It is the space of smooth vector fields on $M$.

@MoisheKohan thanks.

Check the notation index: it shows that the notation $\mathfrak X(M)$ is defined on page 177.

@JackLee Thanks. (Excellent book btw)
